# What tectonic structures delineate the split between the Australian and Indian tectonic plates?

Tags: geophysics, plate-tectonics, tectonics

Growing up, when looking in textbooks and other references about plate tectonics, there was always the Indo-Australian (or Indian-Australian) plate, such as shown below:

[image]

Image source: [The Geologic Story of Yosemite National Park (1987) by N. King Huber](http://www.yosemite.ca.us/library/geologic_story_of_yosemite/rocks.html)

But, recently it has been recognised that there are separate Indian and Australian plates, such as shown below:

[image]

Image source: [An Introduction to
Plate Tectonics](http://eqseis.geosc.psu.edu/~cammon/HTML/Classes/IntroQuakes/Notes/plate_tect01.html)

This would make sense given the differences in the collisional history of the two landmasses.

**What tectonic structures delineate the split between the Australian and Indian tectonic plates?**

Answer (score 3):

The structures are not mature or well defined and deformation was thought to be diffused, i.e., distributed over a large area. Earthquakes such as the M8.6 2012 Indian Ocean earthquake (largest strike-slip earthquake on record) appear to accommodate some, if not all, of the deformation.

Seafloor geodesy is relatively a new field. Most studies are limited to areas near the coast, e.g., US (Cascadia), Japan etc.

Comment: Could you please add some references to your answer.